# Pass test data to table-valued parameter within SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

Is it possible, and if so how, to pass data to a table-valued parameter of a stored function using SQL EXEC?

I know how to pass in data from C#. One of my four stored procs using table-valued parameters is not producing the expected results. I'd like to execute my proc from SQL server management studio for debugging purposes, but I am unable to find the correct syntax for doing so, if such a syntax even exists. I haven't found anything relevant in the docs.

My type table:

```
CREATE TYPE [MyNameSpace].[MyTypeTable] AS TABLE( 
//... all my fields
)
```

My stored proc:

```
//... bunch of stuff
ALTER PROCEDURE [MyNameSpace].[MyStoredProc]
@MyTypeTableVar MyTypeTable READONLY 
AS
BEGIN
//Do a bunch of stuff
//Want to test the stuff in here
END
```

I have tried:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#MyTempTable;
select top 0 *
into #MyTempTable
//existing table with structure that matches the table-valued param
from MyNameSpace.MyTable;

//...Long insert statement assigning test data to #MyTempTable

EXECUTE MyNameSpace.MyStoredProc @MyTypeTableVar = #MyTempTable;
```

which throws:

> Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with MyTypeTable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't use a temp table - you have to use a [table variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
declare @t [MyNameSpace].[MyTypeTable]
insert into @t (/*columns*/) values
(/* first row */),
(/* second row */)

EXECUTE MyNameSpace.MyStoredProc @MyTypeTableVar = @t;
```

(You can populate it with either `INSERT ... VALUES` as shown above or `INSERT ... SELECT` if you have an existing table containing the data you care about)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a working example:

```
-- Declare a table parameter
DECLARE @registryUpdates AS typ_KeyValuePairStringTable;
-- Insert one row
INSERT INTO @registryUpdates 
VALUES ('Hello', 'World');
-- Call Stored Procedure
EXEC prc_UpdateRegistry @registryUpdates
```